# .NET Combining Exists() with First()

Tags: .net, linq, ienumerable

Right now, I have the following code:

```
List<MyType> objectList = MyType.GetList();
MyType objectInstance = new MyType();

if (objectList.Exists(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeValue"))
{
    objectInstance = objectList.First(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeValue"));
    DoStuff();
}
else if (objectList.Exists(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeOtherValue"))
{
    objectInstance = objectList.First(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeOtherValue"));
    DoStuff();
}
```

Is there any way I can avoid having to do the Exists check first, followed by the assignation?

I know that I can use FirstOrDefault instead, as follows:

```
List<MyType> objectList = MyType.GetList();
MyType objectInstance = new MyType();

objectInstance = objectList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeValue"));
if (objectInstance != null)
    DoStuff();
else
{
    objectInstance = objectList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeValue"));
    if (objectInstance != null)
         DoStuff();
}
```

But this doesn't really seem any more efficient.

What I'd like to be able to do is have behaviour similar to TryParse(). I know I could write my own wrapper for this, which I'll do if there is no built-in way of doing it, but figured I'd just check and see before I do. Basically, what I'd like is:

```
List<MyType> objectList = MyType.GetList();
MyType objectInstance = new MyType();

if (objectList.TryFirst(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeValue", out objectInstance))
    DoStuff();
else if (objectList.TryFirst(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeOtherValue", out objectInstance))
    DoStuff();
```

Comment: What makes you think it's inefficient? Did you try it? Was it slow? Are you sure you're not trying to pre-optimize?

Comment: What you are describing is exactly the FirstOrDefault functionality

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have been more clear when I said "efficient" - I wasn't really referring to the actual efficiency of the code, in terms of how fast it ran, or etc...

I was more referring to just the effort of writing the code. Having to repeatedly test whether the object was null just seemed like a waste of time to write.

So I guess the answer to my question is - just write the wrapper to save myself having to write the extra code required for FirstOrDefault?

Comment: How big is your list, typically?  If it's of any significant size, I'd be more concerned about traversing it multiple times than I would about the ease or readability of your code.  If indeed you want the one matching `SomeOtherValue` only when no items match `SomeValue`, then a for-loop would be a better choice than LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var objectInstance = 
    objectList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeValue")) ??
    objectList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeOtherValue"));
if (objectInstance != null) DoStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create lookup by this property of your with first elements:

```
var lookup = objectList.GroupBy(x=> x.MyProperty).ToDictionary(x=> x.MyProperty, x=> x.First());

if(lookup.TryGetValue("SomeValue", out objectInstance) || lookup.TryGetValue("SomeOtherValue", out objectInstance))
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: The OP says _I know that I can use FirstOrDefault instead_ and by the way you call the second FirstOrDefault even if it is not needed because the first one returned a valid object

Comment: Ups, sorry, will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

FirstOrDefault is the TryParse equivalent. When you have separate exists and first checks this will cause the collection to be iterated over twice. For very large lists or IEnumerables backed by a yielded function (for example yielding the results from a SqlDataReader)  this can get very costly.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to shorten source code lines count? OK, you can do something like that (but it's a bit slower because of sorting):

```
var objectInstance = objectList.OrderByDescending(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeValue").ThenByDescending(o => o.MyProperty == "SomeOtherValue").FirstOrDefault();
if (objectInstance.MyProperty == "SomeValue" || objectInstance.MyProperty == "SomeOtherValue")
{
   DoStuff();
}
```

If you are required to find EXACTLY FIRST element in sequence that satisfies your conditions, you can select indices too before sorting.